# How to export different size lists separately with their name in r?

Tags: r

My list is similar this. I have much more lists in `out` data.

```
 out<-structure(list(`1/2018` = structure(list(max = structure(c(1.8, 
    2, 2.4, 2.6, 0.447, 0.844, 1.108, 2.161, 3.4, 5.8, 5.8, 5.8, 
    5.8, 6.4, 6.8, 9.6, 9.4, 9.8), .Names = c("nmaxm5", "nmaxm10", 
    "nmaxm15", "nmaxm30", "dmaxm5", "dmaxm10", "dmaxm15", "dmaxm30", 
    "maxhourly", "maxh2", "maxh3", "maxh4", "maxh5", "maxh6", "maxh8", 
    "maxh12", "maxh18", "maxdaily")), pars = structure(c(5.45754759420737, 
    0.805872672741754, 0.0864196916097323, 0.82340519194531, 0.129473255000865, 
    13.8604432013852), .Names = c("a", "l", "v", "k", "f", "mx")), 
        stats = structure(list(mean1 = 0.0769230769230769, mean6 = 0.459677419354839, 
            mean12 = 0.919354838709677, mean24 = 1.83870967741935, 
            var1 = 0.0922910602910603, var6 = 1.27478363493312, var12 = 3.57043892120571, 
            var24 = 7.31311827956989, pdr1 = 0.869095816464238, pdr6 = 0.685483870967742, 
            pdr12 = 0.612903225806452, pdr24 = 0.516129032258065, 
            cov1lag1 = 0.0330492138402447, cov6lag1 = 0.416992611023464, 
            cov12lag1 = 0.550831627001443, cov24lag1 = 0.845570809976167), .Names = c("mean1", 
        "mean6", "mean12", "mean24", "var1", "var6", "var12", "var24", 
        "pdr1", "pdr6", "pdr12", "pdr24", "cov1lag1", "cov6lag1", 
        "cov12lag1", "cov24lag1")), dismax = c(0.447, 0.844, 1.108, 
        2.161), normax = c(1.8, 2, 2.4, 2.6), corr = 0.919749257463505), .Names = c("max", 
    "pars", "stats", "dismax", "normax", "corr")), `2/2018` = structure(list(
        max = structure(c(0.8, 1.4, 2, 3.6, 0.76, 1.223, 1.645, 2.828, 
        6.4, 11, 12, 14.2, 18.4, 14.8, 15, 18.8, 14.8, 18.8), .Names = c("nmaxm5", 
        "nmaxm10", "nmaxm15", "nmaxm30", "dmaxm5", "dmaxm10", "dmaxm15", 
        "dmaxm30", "maxhourly", "maxh2", "maxh3", "maxh4", "maxh5", 
        "maxh6", "maxh8", "maxh12", "maxh18", "maxdaily")), pars = structure(c(4.56733723844994, 
        0.875148691439675, 0.145445549011324, 1.34160386037642, 0.49939954811621, 
        24.0665460593286), .Names = c("a", "l", "v", "k", "f", "mx"
        )), stats = structure(list(mean1 = 0.137031484257871, mean6 = 0.816071428571429, 
            mean12 = 1.63214285714286, mean24 = 3.26428571428571, 
            var1 = 0.333566550058304, var6 = 5.26640604890605, var12 = 14.5553116883117, 
            var24 = 31.6920105820106, pdr1 = 0.880059970014992, pdr6 = 0.732142857142857, 
            pdr12 = 0.607142857142857, pdr24 = 0.428571428571429, 
            cov1lag1 = 0.245781926103677, cov6lag1 = 2.10700981117894, 
            cov12lag1 = 2.47639736698251, cov24lag1 = 2.54929118075802), .Names = c("mean1", 
        "mean6", "mean12", "mean24", "var1", "var6", "var12", "var24", 
        "pdr1", "pdr6", "pdr12", "pdr24", "cov1lag1", "cov6lag1", 
        "cov12lag1", "cov24lag1")), dismax = c(0.76, 1.223, 1.645, 
        2.828), normax = c(0.8, 1.4, 2, 3.6), corr = 0.999940177186404), .Names = c("max", 
    "pars", "stats", "dismax", "normax", "corr"))), .Names = c("1/2018", 
    "2/2018"))
```

I want to export `out` list to excel or csv. And as output, I want to see `1/2018.xlsx` and `2/2018.xlsx` separately in my documents folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a function which will turn each list into a dataframe. I am using `rowr::cbind.fill` here to fill uneven columns with `NA`

```
create_dataframe <- function(x) {
   setNames(do.call(rowr::cbind.fill, c(x, fill = NA)), names(x))
}
```

Apply the function to each list

```
listed_data <- lapply(out, create_dataframe)
```

and now write each into different files

```
Map(function(x, y) writexl::write_xlsx(x, paste0(y, ".xlsx")) , 
                            listed_data, names(listed_data))
```

where one dataframe looks like the following

```
listed_data[1]
#$`1/2018`
#     max        pars      stats dismax normax      corr
#1  1.800  5.45754759 0.07692308  0.447    1.8 0.9197493
#2  2.000  0.80587267 0.45967742  0.844    2.0        NA
#3  2.400  0.08641969 0.91935484  1.108    2.4        NA
#4  2.600  0.82340519 1.83870968  2.161    2.6        NA
#5  0.447  0.12947326 0.09229106     NA     NA        NA
#6  0.844 13.86044320 1.27478363     NA     NA        NA
#7  1.108          NA 3.57043892     NA     NA        NA
#8  2.161          NA 7.31311828     NA     NA        NA
#9  3.400          NA 0.86909582     NA     NA        NA
#10 5.800          NA 0.68548387     NA     NA        NA
#11 5.800          NA 0.61290323     NA     NA        NA
#12 5.800          NA 0.51612903     NA     NA        NA
#13 5.800          NA 0.03304921     NA     NA        NA
#14 6.400          NA 0.41699261     NA     NA        NA
#15 6.800          NA 0.55083163     NA     NA        NA
#16 9.600          NA 0.84557081     NA     NA        NA
#17 9.400          NA         NA     NA     NA        NA
#18 9.800          NA         NA     NA     NA        NA
```

Answer (score 1):

With `library(xlsx)`, maybe you can make it through the code below:

```
sapply(seq_along(out), function(k) write.xlsx(unlist(out[[k]]), gsub("/","-",paste0(names(out)[k],".xlsx"))))
```

Note that you may have problem when you have `/` in your file name, so I replace `/` by `-`